# Why not delete answers that are opinions rather than questions that are difficult to answer without them?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers

[Are conspiracy theories evil?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/97557/are-conspiracy-theories-evil)

I don't see why anyone would read this question to be asking for anyone's opinion, but it was closed for that reason. It's probably true that most discussion about conspiracies won't discuss evil and whether an act of conspiracy makes something more morally suspect. But, in general, aren't the resulting answers against site rules, rather than the questions themselves?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you follow the link in the notification, you can find more elaborate descriptions of and the rationales behind the close-reasons.

For this close reason, that which the voters see is the following:

> This question is likely to be answered with opinions rather than facts and citations. It should be updated so it will lead to fact-based answers.

As you can see, it is not necessarily about whether it *could* be answered objectively, but about whether *it is likely* that this will happen.

It becomes already unlikely as soon as you have a topic with bipartisan positions on it. And it certainly happens the more *fuzzy terms* you use. Good and evil are like *the fuzziest* terms there are. You can discuss it till Judgement Day and won't reach any definite answer.

Thus, I'd advise to very succintly define your terms in a question. This heightens the chances of it receiving a benevolent reaction and a good answer considerably. It also is a test: If you are unable to do so, others will probably struggle as well.

Comment: OK I get it. Strange policy

Comment: @opinionated As a matter of fact, a considerable part of training in academic philosophy is learning to ask and write in clear terms, ie. you learn to very carefully frame the meaning of what you want to hear and say/write. The first thing you realise on that way is that communication is not a one-way-track: More often than not, you just *know* what you understand under certain terms while others can have a great variety in understandings. The second thing you realise thinking about it is that when that happens and you try to make yourself more clear, you can't since *your thought* is fuzzy.

Comment: i don't much think that we cannot use the term evil and good as shorthand etc. but it's fine

Comment: i think you set the bar too high in asking not just for clarity but to demonstrate your clarity. it is not asked of everyone here